# Children picking parents before birth. Is it biblical?

Tags: biblical-basis, foreknowledge

Is there anywhere in the bible where it says that babies choose or pick their parents before birth? Do children already know their parents before birth?

Comment: Though this doesn't answer your question, the answers to [this other question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15407/what-is-the-basis-for-the-belief-among-some-lds-mormons-that-children-in-their-p) may be of some interest to you.

Comment: This strikes me as a strange question. Are you simply curious? Or is this a cultural concept that you're wondering about a biblical basis for? Is it a teaching of some church?

Comment: Hi Toya! I'm looking at your question and it seems to me that it doesn't fit well for our site. What we're looking for here are questions that can be definitively answered (i.e. answered without room for interpretation); that usually means "answered from the point of view of some Christian group". *Is there in fact* some Christian group that believes this? If so, could you point them out to us? I can't think of one.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This question is off-topic and does not fit into one of the [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409) If possible, [edit] this question so that it better fits into one of those question types.

Comment: LDS (Mormons) believe in a pre-existence. They are a relatively small group of Christians, however. Most other Christians do not believe in such a thing.

Comment: To bring this question into site guidelines I suggest that you ask if Mormons specifically believe this or not, since they are really the only ones that believe in a pre-existence in the first place.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a verse request question.

Comment: If they did, why wouldn't they remember it?  And how could anyone expect them to pick with no knowledge?  Are we talking "picking" by spinning a Wheel of Fortune, because that's the only conceivable way they could pick, and that's not really picking.

Answer (score 6):

### Nope

Kids knowing their parents before they're born isn't mentioned in the bible. Scripture does, however, talk about how God knows each person before they're born.

> **Jeremiah 1:5 ESV** Before I formed you in the womb I knew you, and before you were born I consecrated you; I appointed you a prophet to the nations.

Comment: I agree, but I hesitate to vote this answer up since I consider it incomplete.  It would be better if you gave some information about the people who do believe this to be true and from where they do derive this belief.  Also, it would be helpful to state whether or not there are any major denominations which do hold this as official doctrine.

Answer (score 2):

Although I do not know everything that is said in the Bible, I can find no place where the children choose their parents, nor do I find any place where the parents choose their children. I do find several places where God decides who does and who does not have Children.

> Psalms 127:3 through 5 KJV  Lo, children are an heritage of the LORD: and the fruit of the womb is his reward. 4  As arrows are in the hand of a mighty man; so are children of the youth. 5  Happy is the man that hath his quiver full of them: they shall not be ashamed, but they shall speak with the enemies in the gate.
>
> Deuteronomy 30:9 KJV  And the LORD thy God will make thee plenteous in every work of thine hand, in the fruit of thy body, and in the fruit of thy cattle, and in the fruit of thy land, for good: for the LORD will again rejoice over thee for good, as he rejoiced over thy fathers:

AS I read this God chooses to give children to parents as a reward, and that can be understood in several ways. Good children might be thought of as a reward for good, and bad children could be considered a reward for bad behavior.

But we also must consider it from God's perspective, and that is a bit harder to contemplate.

> Matthew 18:12 and 13 KJV  How think ye? if a man have an hundred sheep, and one of them be gone astray, doth he not leave the ninety and nine, and goeth into the mountains, and seeketh that which is gone astray? 13  And if so be that he find it, verily I say unto you, he rejoiceth more of that sheep, than of the ninety and nine which went not astray.

God will make every effort to bring all to salvation.

> Matthew 18:14 KJV  Even so it is not the will of your Father which is in heaven, that one of these little ones should perish.

Paul in his first epistle to the Corinthians said:

> 1st. Corinthians 7:16 KJV  For what knowest thou, O wife, whether thou shalt save thy husband? or how knowest thou, O man, whether thou shalt save thy wife?

So from my Southern Baptist concept I extend that to say that you may need to do a little self examination, to determine exactly why God chose you specifically to be the child of your parents. Was it a reward for good, for bad, or possibly as the person to lead them and /or many others into the Kingdom of God.

Comment: Good generalization of the question. I agree that God does the choosing, which is fortunate for us.